# ss or ip equivalent to netstat -gn to show multicast memberships?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, netstat

Is there a modern Linux tool that will show the equivalent of `netstat -gn` to show multicast group memberships? This old command shows output like this:

```
IPv6/IPv4 Group Memberships
Interface       RefCnt Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
...
p3p1            1      239.151.10.1
p3p2            1      239.152.10.1
```

The key is that first column. As we advance towards a future in which netstat and ifconfig are no longer used, I'd hate to lose this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this will do the trick:

```
ip -4 -o maddr show
```

Will show:

```
6:      p3p1\   inet  239.151.10.1
8:      p3p2\   inet  239.152.10.1
```

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find good documentation for the STRING required after `dev`. Strangely, I could put any character I wanted there and the output would be similar. Regardless, I've removed it. `-4` is a good idea.